# Getting the last record in a join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, greatest-n-per-group

i have a problem here and i didn't understand the posts about the subject. So here is my question:

In my application i have the following entities:

```
Customer( CustomerId int, Name varchar(200), Email varchar(100), ...)
Employee (EmployeeId int, Name varchar(200), Email varchar(100), ...)
Sale(SaleId int, CustomerId int, EmployeeId int, SaleDate datetime, ...) Join Table
```

How can i get the last sale for each customer in the table?

Example (Sample data):

```
Customer:
    1, John Smith, jonh@smith.com, ...
    2, Michael Jackson, michael@jackson.com, ...
    3, Bill Clinton, bill@clinton.com, ...

Employee:
   1, Steve Jobs, steve@jobs.com, ...
   2, Bill Gates, bill@gates.com, ...
   3, Mark Zuckerberg, mark@zuckerberg.com, ...

Sales:
   1, 1 (John Smith), 1 (Steve Jobs), '2013-01-02'
   2, 1 (John Smith), 2 (Bill Gates), '2013-01-11'
   3, 1 (John Smith), 3 (Mark Zuckerberg), '2012-12-25'
   4, 2 (Michael Jackson), 2 (Bill Gates), '2012-11-02'
   5, 2 (Michael Jackson), 1 (Steve Jobs), '2013-01-13'
   6, 3 (Bill Clinton), 3 (Mark Zuckerberg), '2013-01-17'
   7, 3 (Bill Clinton), 2 (Bill Gates), '2011-12-20'
```

My result query has to bring me the following result:

```
   2, 1 (John Smith), 2 (Bill Gates), '2013-01-11'
   5, 2 (Michael Jackson), 1 (Steve Jobs), '2013-01-13'
   6, 3 (Bill Clinton), 3 (Mark Zuckerberg), '2013-01-17'
```

Comment: @JW. I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that you are using `SQL Server`, make use of `Common Table Expression` and `Window Function`

```
WITH latestRecords
AS
(
    SELECT  SaleId , CustomerId, EmployeeId , SaleDate,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId
                                ORDER BY SaleDate DESC) RN
    FROM    Sale
)
SELECT  a.SaleId,
        b.Name AS CustomerName,
        c.Name as EmployeeName,
        a.SaleDate
FROM    latestRecords a
        INNER JOIN Customer b
            ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN Employee c
            ON a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
WHERE   a.RN = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d920/4)